# Hopkins statistic in clustering

Tags: clustering

Some papers explain that the Hopkins statistic H, which tests cluster tendency, shows that data are clusterable if H> 0.5. Other papers use 0.6 or 0.75 as a threshold value. Which threshold value should I use? For example, if it is 0.6, can I state that the data may be clusterable, but the cluster-tendency is weak? Or should I test if the H obtained under the null hypothesis is significant ( it should follow a beta distribution) rather than just seeing if it exceeds 0.5?

H changes depending on the number of samples (m) when calculating H, so please also tell me how to determine m. Some papers use m = n / 10 as a guide, but other papers explain that m can be larger than n/10.

Comment: As I wrote elsewhere, "being clusterable" is not a property of the data on their own. It depends on your aim of clustering, the meaning of the data etc. Such threshold values are largely arbitrary. There are well known problems with the Hopkins Statistic see for example second answer here   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332651/validating-cluster-tendency-using-hopkins-statistic and the literature is a mess, so I can't help much with this.

Comment: @Lewian: Thank you very much. I read the original paper by Hopkins (1954) and learned that it suggested the statistical test.

Comment: Yes, you can use it as a well defined statistical test to reject a specific model for homogeneity. The thing is that rejecting this model doesn't imply at all that there are meaningful clusters. So some people thought that more needs to be demanded than just significance, and proposed values that set the bar for clusterability higher. But as far as I know there are no well defined formal reasons for any of these. People know that the user doesn't want to make decisions, so they suggest a default cutoff value, maybe from a bit of experience. But ultimately these are arbitrary.